# How to get the metrics generated at runtime (skywalking 9.2, Java)

Tags: java, runtime, metrics, apm, skywalking

I can get the metrics (through the Skywalking UI) which configured in a yaml file (local at /xxxx/apache-skywalking-apm-bin/config/meter-analyzer-config/xxx.yaml) , like this:

```yaml
metricsRules:
  - name: tmTotalMemorySegments
    exp: tmTotalMemorySegments
```

We can see the "name" is fixed, my question is , is there a way to specific a name like "tmTotal.*" to expose the metrics which name starts with "tmTotal"?

That is, my metric name is unknown before my application is run (maybe I can know the prefix of metric name), but only at runtime.